# Listing of items in order of their effectiveness

Tags: lists, comparisons

In a research paper, how do I list things in order of their effectiveness?

For example,

> The order of antagonistic effect of acetic acid against E. coli O157:H7 was salt > glycine > glucose > sucrose.

Is it okay to use ">" or "<" in a sentence for a research paper?
It looks a bit weird to me. Is there a better way or any other way to write this down correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is extremely important to state within the sentence the **nature** of the order:

> The <strike>order of</strike> antagonistic effect of acetic acid against E. coli  O157:H7 in **decreasing** order was salt > glycine > glucose > sucrose.

The symbol > should not be expected to represent 'greater than' in a plain English sentence. It will most likely be seen as a list separator or delimiter only. That is, as equivalent to:

> The antagonistic effect of acetic acid against E. coli  O157:H7 in decreasing order was salt, glycine, glucose, sucrose.

However,

> The **levels** of antagonistic effect of acetic acid against E. coli  O157:H7 were:
>   salt > glycine > glucose > sucrose

could probably invoke the 'greater than' sense of the symbol.

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter of style. The ultimate authority will be whatever style guide you are supposed to adopt, such as the APA.

Without a style guide to guide you, you would normally write as you speak. If you would say

> The order of antagonistic effect of acetic acid against E. coli O157:H7 was salt, glycine, glucose, and sucrose.

then that is how you would write it.

Comment: I'll also add that since you're (probably) not writing this paper as a weekend hobby, but in the context of a specific university, a specific department, and a specific professor, you should probably just ask. Chances are, this has come up before in your close environment.

Comment: @MετάEd Thanks for the answer. But can you tell which one is more effective? "The order of antagonistic effect of acetic acid against E. coli O157:H7 was salt, glycine, glucose, and sucrose." Maybe adding or stating strong to weak order or starting with strongest first?

Comment: @handicop:  Yes, if you wanted to be crystal clear I would say:  "The order was (strongest to weakest) A, B, C, D."

Comment: @Avner Shahar-Kashtan Yes, I would do that if this was my paper. I am just helping my friend writing her paper in English. Writing a research paper in English without a writing center supporting students would be very tough but I guess it's a common thing in Asia.